# Передача переменных в cmake

Tags: cmake

Я пытаюсь понять, как работает механизм передачи переменных из командной строки (или командного файла `cmd/sh`) в `cmake`. Внятного объяснения найти не получилось.

Например, я хочу сделать так, чтобы командный файл выставлял путь для переменной `BOOST_ROOT`, а потом - запускал сборку.

Например, я делаю так (в `build.sh`):

```
export BOOST_ROOT=path
```

Этого достаточно?

Или же мне нужно в `CMakeLists.txt` организовать еще и *проброс* этой переменной, чтобы **cmake** увидел эту штуку, как свою внутреннюю переменную?

Или же для (конкретно) переменной `BOOST_ROOT` внутри `cmake` уже есть собственная обвязка, которая осуществляет все необходимые действия по анализу имеющихся переменных окружения и *пробросу*?

Какие вообще существуют варианты передачи переменных в `cmake` из вне и из самих скриптов `cmake`?

Comment: Используйте `-DBOOST_ROOT=...`

Comment: @dIm0n, почему? И как?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12896988/13970074